# How to set a break-point to a line in debugging prolog?

Tags: prolog, logic

In Yap, I'm debugging a program and it reads a lot data from a file. I would like to ask whether there are some ways to set a break-point to a LINE in prolog file. I know there is a predicate called `spy` which allows you to set the program stop at an expected predicate, however if this predicate calls sub-predicates, how can I set a break-point to the sub-predicates? For example:

```
pA :-
  pB, 
  pC.
```

How can I set a break-point to stop at pC(in case pC is a built-in predicate) since `spy` only allows me to set break-point at pA. Thanks very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current Logtalk git version supports the definition of file line number spy points. YAP is one Prolog backend compilers supported by Logtalk. The feasibility of using the Logtalk debugger for debugging your program depends, however, if it's structured using Prolog modules. If so, it should be possible to compile your Prolog modules as objects by simply changing the file name extensions from Prolog to Logtalk (i.e. from `.pl` or `.yap` to `.lgt`) and using the Logtalk compiling and loading predicates.